# Error during access to .ashx page in IIS 7 on windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, web-server, soap

I have web site on IIS 7 on Windows 2008, when I try to access the "page" (that correctly bound to namespace in web.config) I get error:
"The required page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid".

Very important to say that on windows 7 I have this working.

May be this is because I don't see ASP.NET area in management window?
If yes, can yo tell me how I install ASP.NET on IIS 7 on windows 2008?

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The .ashx is part of HandlerFactory which is installed when you select ASP.NET in the Web Server Role Services.

To enable ASP.NET in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008

In Windows 7, you can enable ASP.NET from `Control Panel` -> `Programs` -> `Programs and Features` -> `Turn Windows features on or off`. Expand `Internet Information Services` -> `World Wide Web Services` -> `Application Development Features` and click `ASP.NET`.

In Windows Server 2008, Open `Server Manager` -> click `Roles` -> click `Add Roles` -> select `Web Server (IIS)` -> in Role Services click `ASP.NET` it will prompt for necessary dependent Roles Services `click Add Required Role Services`.